# Django BooleanField as radio buttons at the Inlineadmin

Tags: django, django-admin

I couldn't find a street way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a street way to do it, so I make tweak with JavaScript to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".field-current").live("click",function(){

    $action = $($(this).children()[0])
    current_state = $action.is(':checked');
    $('.field-current').each(function(index) {
      var $temp = $($(this).children()[0])
      $temp.val(false);  
      $temp.attr('checked', false);
    });

    var $current = $($(this).children()[0])
    if (current_state == "on" || current_state == true){  
      $current.val(true);
      $current.attr('checked', true);
    }else{
      $current.val(false);
      $current.attr('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

in the admin page add

```
class ArticleDetailsInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
     ....
    fields     = ['current', 'slug','summary','mod_date']

class ArticleHeaderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ArticleDetailsInlineAdmin,]
    ......
    form = ArticleForm

class Media:
        js = ('js/admin-current-article.js')
```

by doing this the current field will act like radio button among the inlineadmin

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) property to change the widget used (it's available on InlineAdmin classes as well as ModelAdmin):

```
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect

class ArticleDetailsInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    ...
    fields = ['current', 'slug', 'summary', 'mod_date']
    formfield_overrides = {
            models.BooleanField: {'widget': RadioSelect},
        }
```

Note this will use radio buttons instead of checkboxes for *all* BooleanFields in ArticleDetailsInlineAdmin.

Comment: Hmm sorry, didn't have a chance to test it. You might have to define a custom widget which inherits from the RadioSelect widget but implements the correct logic to handle a BooleanField correctly. Could you approach this from the other side and change your BooleanField to a ChoiceField?